# Django REST API - serializer with different format for read and write?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF to run some AJAX backend endpoints. I have these two models:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey('Quiz', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='teams')
```

I'm then using DRF's generics to create a basic read/write endpoint:

```
class TeamList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Team.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TeamSerializer
```

and a ModelSerializer

```
class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'quiz']
```

I can `POST` it some JSON with a quiz ID to create a team:

```
{"quiz": 123, "name": "My Team Name"}
```

But I'd like the `GET` version to include the quiz title:

```
{"quiz": {"id": 123, "title": "My Quiz Title"}, "id": 234, "name": "My Team Name"}
```

What's the best way to do that? Have two Serializers and override the ListCreateAPIView.list() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably have two serializers, but one ViewSet where the `get_serializer_class` is overridden.

```
class BaseTeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'quiz']

class CreateTeamSerializer(BaseTeamSerializer):
    pass

class TeamSerializer(BaseTeamSerializer):
    quiz = QuizSerializer(many=False)


class TeamViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                  mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                  mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Team.objects.all()
    
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == "POST":
            return CreateTeamSerializer # Or could use BaseTeamSerializer
        return TeamSerializer
```

Comment: Ah, viewsets isn't something I've really grokked yet. Ok, time to do some more reading. Thanks very much for the response.